# How to take full-resolution screenshots on iPhone? (Getting reduced from 1242 x 2208 to 674 x 1200)

Tags: iphone, ios

I've downloaded an app (that I built - I am preparing to submit) on my iPhone 6s Plus and I'm trying to prepare some screenshots for the App Store. Per documentation, the screenshots should be `1242 x 2208px`, however when I take a screenshot and open it up on my desktop, I'm left with `674 x 1200px`. What can I do to get the proper resolution for these screenshots?

Comment: How/where do you take the screenshots, how do you transfer them to your Mac?

Answer (score 5):

Screenshots should be in full resolution, but the way you send it to yourself may cause the resolution to be reduced. In particular, Google Inbox reduces the resolution of photos by default when emailing them.

You should be okay sending it to yourself using Apple Mail, and selecting full resolution.

Comment: iOS Shared Albums also cause the resolution to be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

**iPhone 6s Plus**

Your iPhone 6s Plus has a 1920 x 1080 pixel resolution at 401 psi which, as you say, should produce 1242 x 2208 pixel screenshots (in portrait). I can't explain why you're getting screenshots at 674 x 1200, except that how you're transferring them to your computer may be causing the change?

If you're emailing them be sure to pick the highest quality (if prompted). Otherwise you should be able to message them to your Mac as well.

**iOS Simulator**

If neither seem to work, probably the best way to generate your screenshots is to use the iOS Simulator. To do this:

- Build and run your app via Xcode to the appropriate Simulator
- Ensure the app is displayed at 100% scale (you can check this from the Window > Scale menu in Simulator).
- Take your screenshots from within Simulator using the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut (or going to File > Save Screenshot)
- Once you have the screenshots you need, upload them to iTunes Connect.

NOTES:

1. If you're wanting to just upload one set of screenshots for the iPhone, then ensure you're using a simulator for the 5.5" iPhone.
2. If you also need to upload screenshots for the iPad and only want one set, then choose the Simulator for the 12.9" iPad.

Any questions, just ask.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response, but the issue is simply that on the 5.5" model, the resolution is coming out to be `674 x 1200 px` when I open its screenshots on my computer.

Comment: How are you taking the screenshot?

Comment: Power+home buttons together on the device

Comment: Hmmm, the iPhone 6s Plus has a 1920 x 1080 pixel resolution at 401 ppi, so I can't explain why you're getting screenshots at 674 x 1200. How are you transferring them to your computer? Maybe something is happening through that process?

Comment: Same issue. Raw screenshots are downscaled.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756882/145173), you can use the iOS Simulator to get a full-resolution screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:
Go to settings -> Display and Brightness -> View -> Choose standard instead of zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

To save and forward any Screen shot from an iPhone with the original screen resolution, just follow the below steps.

1. Take the screen shot
2. Save the screen shot to files (on your apple device)
3. then share it using AirDrop.